# Don't move project outside workspace while creating a EGit repo in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am working on a project which I want keep in my workspace.
Also I want to create a repo from this project using EGit.
It's a normal behavior of EGit that it moves my files to GitRepos directory while creating a repo.

I want to know if there is any way through which I can keep my project files inside Workspace and also keep a copy these files into GitRepos folder so that each time do changes/commit into GitRepos folder.

Because I want to separate my development environment with Production/Live environment as as I am using this GitRepo as my default live code on server.